# ng-model value does not reflect in the select-option

Tags: angularjs

When I try to click edit on a page view, it displays the values as editable. One property, `device.exists` is a boolean, but when the original value is `false` and when I click edit, the first option `true` still displays. How would I make the selection `option` reflect the original value of the model?

```
<select ng-model="device.exists">
    <option value="true">true</option>
    <option value="false">false</option>
</select>
```

P.S. I didn't use `ng-value` because it is not available to Hawtio's AngularJS version 1.1.5 which I am using.

Comment: Works fine - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFGqthWjyDiXeuFKc59c?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, I think we need more code to understand your problem. This much should work perfectly fine. This 'edit' thing for instance ?